# Changing black color to white but not white color to black with Python openCV PIL

Tags: python, opencv

Im trying to change black pixels to white with opencv in python using cv2 or PIL.

Original picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = cv2.imread("numptest/captcha.png")
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

lower_black = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_black = np.array([1,1,1])
black_mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower_black, upper_black)
cv2.imshow('mask0',black_mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

while I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I have tried also this code, which does preserve what is inside those rectangles, but works only for exactly RGB 255 255 255, while i need it to work for wider range of RGB.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('numptest/captcha.png')
im = im.convert('RGBA')
data = np.array(im)   
black_areas = (red == 0) & (blue == 0) & (green == 0)
data[..., :-1][black_areas.T] = (255, 255, 255)

im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
im2.show()'
```

Here is result of second code:

[image]

So I dont know, maybe best would be some combination of these codes, I just dont really understand how to use inRange in second code, that would probably solve my problem.

Comment: If it is a greyscale image why not use it as a greyscale image and and change everything below, lets say 10 (almost black) to 255 (white). With in range, you have to define which colors are in valid range using a lower bound and upper bound, then use this as a mask and color that area white. In [this tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) they show you how to filter by color, by upperr bound I would use something close to black (10,10,10) and lower bound just black (0,0,0) since black is not always pure

Answer (score 1):

Actauly I found answer to my own question while writing the question. I just altered the second code.

this line:

```
       black_areas = (red == 0) & (blue == 0) & (green == 0)
```

with this line:

```
    black_areas = (red < 70) & (blue < 70) & (green < 70)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Fortunately in most cases its not and I dont need 100% accuracy, even 10% is good enough for me, but im sure there are much better solutions for this problem. I will further evaluate the best number, maybe 70 is too high and this is not the last step in whole process either.